Combining Rows into Columns Based on a Condition
I have the following table:



Eqp
Date
Value




Eqp 1
01/12/2024
2500


Eqp 2
01/12/2024
2500



I want to transform it into this format:



Eqp
Another Eqp
Date
Value




Eqp 1
Eqp 2
01/12/2024
2500



The idea is to combine rows with the same Date and Value into a single row, where the second equipment (Another Eqp) appears as a column.
I attempted to use ROW_NUMBER() and CASE WHEN to assign row numbers to each record, intending to pivot the rows into columns. However, the result was incorrect. I ended up with something like this:



Eqp
Another Eqp
Date
Value




Eqp 1
NULL
01/12/2024
2500


NULL
Eqp 1
01/12/2024
2500



The issue is that I couldn’t correctly match the rows and move the second equipment into the Another Eqp column.

You can use ROW_NUMBER and then PIVOT:
SELECT eqp1,
       eqp2,
       eqp3,
       dt,
       value
FROM   (
  SELECT eqp,
         dt,
         value,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY dt, value ORDER BY eqp) AS rn
  FROM   table_name
)
PIVOT (
  MAX(eqp)
  FOR rn IN (
    1 AS eqp1,
    2 AS eqp2,
    3 AS eqp3
  )
)

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE table_name (Eqp, dt, Value) AS
SELECT 'Eqp 1', DATE '2024-12-01', 2500 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Eqp 2', DATE '2024-12-01', 2500 FROM DUAL;

Outputs:



EQP1
EQP2
EQP3
DT
VALUE




Eqp 1
Eqp 2
null
2024-12-01 00:00:00
2500



fiddle

Its almost same as the above answer, I have used CASE instead of PIVOT.
Fiddle
WITH NumberedEquipment AS (
    SELECT
        Eqp,
        Date_col,
        Value1,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Date_col, Value1 ORDER BY Eqp) AS Row_Num
    FROM test_table
)
SELECT
    MAX(CASE WHEN Row_Num = 1 THEN Eqp END) AS "Eqp",
    MAX(CASE WHEN Row_Num = 2 THEN Eqp END) AS "Another Eqp",
    Date_col,
    Value1
FROM NumberedEquipment
GROUP BY Date_col, Value1;

Output


Thank you so much @GabrielG.Martins for letting me know and glad you found it helpful :)
